# hydrated cubit doesn't store state

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-cubit

In the following cubit, I tried to persist the state of the navigation of the application but when killing the app on the device and returning to the program it returns to the default state. How can I solve the problem?

My cubit is:

```dart
class NavigationCubit extends HydratedCubit<NavigationState> {
  NavigationCubit() : super(NavigationState.empty);


  @override
  NavigationState fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      NavigationState.fromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(NavigationState state) => state.toJson();
}
```

State code is:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class NavigationState {
  final PagesTitle currentPage;
  final PagesTitle targetPage;

  const NavigationState({required this.currentPage, required this.targetPage});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$NavigationStateToJson(this);

  factory NavigationState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$NavigationStateFromJson(json);

  static const NavigationState empty = NavigationState(
    currentPage: PagesTitle.dashboard,
    targetPage: PagesTitle.unknown,
  );

}

enum PagesTitle { chart, payout, dashboard, profile, setting, unknown }
```

Comment: how have you implemented navigation and how are you listening to NavigationState changes?

Comment: I used go router package with a redirect parameter set to listen to `state` changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `HydratedMixin` instead of `HydratedCubit`

```
class NavigationCubit extends Cubit< NavigationState> with HydratedMixin {
  NavigationCubit() : super(Navigationitial());

  void setNavigationState({required UserData userData}) {
    emit( NavigationState(userData: userData.toJson()));
  }

  @override
  NavigationState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NavigationState.fromMap(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(NavigationState state) {
    return state.toMap();
  }
}
```